# Mapping backorders/allow_backorders & use_config_backorders (Akeneo)

Tags: magento2, database, backorder, mapping, upward-connector

I've not been succesful in mapping these values, as these are not standard product attributes.

- backorders (or allow_backorders)
- use_config_backorders

I would not mind setting the default value of use_config_backorders to 0 (unchecked) in the database, but I can't seem to find this attribute in the eav_attribute table.

For setting allow_backorders I currently use the product import in magento backend, but I seek to automaticaly update this based on an attribute in Akeneo. Mapping a boolean or int value to either backorder, backorders or allow_backorders does not change the value in Magento. No matter if I use the same attribute code in Magento and Akeneo or not.

A workaround might be an automatic product import script (as I know that allow_backorders changes perfectly based on a value in a csv), but that'll be my last resort.

My questions are:

- Where is allow_backorders (or backorders) and use_config_backorders stored in the magento database? (not in eav_attributes)
- follow-up: can they somehow be mapped with the Magento-Akeneo connector?

[image]